# Passing a dict-like Object through multiprocessing.Queue Makes it Unable to be Modified by Attribute

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Actually I am not sure whether the title describes the problem appropriately. Let me show the code.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue

# A dict-like class, but is able to be accessed by attributes.
# example: d = AttrDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
# d.a is equivalent to d['a']
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self


queue = JoinableQueue()
pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    d = AttrDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
    queue.put(d)
    queue.join()
    os._exit(0)
else:
    d = queue.get()
    queue.task_done()
    #d = AttrDict(d.items())  #(1)
    d.a = 3                   #(2)
    #d['a'] = 3               #(3)
    print d
```

The above code prints `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, which means (2) is not taking any effect.

If I change (2) to (3), or enable (1), then the output is `{'a': 3, 'b': 2}`, which is expected.

Seems something happened to `d` when it is passed through queue.

Tested with Python 2.7.

---

Solution:

As pointed out by @kindall and @Blckknght, the reason is that `d` is picked as a dict and when it is unpickled by `queue.get()`, the `self.__dict__ = self` magic is not set. The difference can be seem by `print d.__dict__` and `print d`.

To set the magic back, I added the method `__setstate__` to `AttrDict`:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__ = state
```

The code now works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a multiprocessing issue, as `mutlprocessing.Queue` uses `pickle` to serialize and unserialize the objects you are sending through it. The problem lies with `pickle` not correctly preserving the "magic" behavior you get when you set `self.__dict__ = self`.

If you check the object you get in the child process, you'll find that its `__dict__` is just an ordinary dictionary, with the same contents as the object itself. When you set a new attribute on the object, its `__dict__` gets updated, but the inherited dictionary `self` does not. Here's what I mean:

```
>>> d = AttrDict({"a":1, "b":2})
>>> d2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d, -1))
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2.b = 3
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'b': 3}
```

While you could dive into the nitty gritty details of how `pickle` works and get your serialization working again, I think a simpler approach would be to rely on less magical behavior by having your class override the `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` methods:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    __slots__ = () # we don't need a __dict__

    def __getattr__(self, name): # wrapper around dict.__setitem__, with an exception fix
        try:
            return self[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name) from None # raise the right type of exception

    def __delattr__(self, name): # wrapper around dict.__delitem__
        try:
            del self[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name) from None # change exception type here too

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__ # no special exception rewriting needed here
```

Instances of this class will work just like your own, but they can be pickled and unpickled successfully:

```
>>> d = AttrDict({"a":1, "b":2})
>>> d2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d, -1)) # serialize and unserialize
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2.b=3
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: Your implementation is more explicit. I will consider it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since it's a subclass of `dict`, your `AttrDict` is serialized as a `dict`. In particular the `__dict__` pointing to `self` is probably not preserved. You can customize the serialization using certain magic methods; see [this article](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#pickling).